# Php 7.1 Illegal string offset

Tags: php7, php5

Здравствуйте!
Попробовал перевести сайт на php с 5.6 - > 7.1

В ответ получил частую у многих ошибку "Illegal string offset".

В моём не хорошем коде используется следующая конструкция:

Инициализация переменной ( как строка ).

```
$objects = "";
```

В доп. переменную в цикле заносится результат mysqli_fetch_assoc ( массив ).

```
$getcats_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

В цикле в переменную $objects элемента $i ( $objects становится массивом ) заносится массив. Т.е. по моей логике элемент массива $objects содержит массив к которому можно обращаться по его идентификаторам.

```
$objects[$i] = (array) $getcats_row;
```

В данном случае это у нас одно из полей которые были запрошены в mysql.

```
if($objects[$checkid]["parent_id"] == $cat)...
```

Повторюсь, как я понимаю это:

1. $objects - массив.
2. [$checkid] - элемент массива $object являющийся массивом.
3. ["parent_id"] - элемент конечного массива.

Как следствие в php 5.6 Обращение происходит корректно. На выходе есть данные.

В php 7.1 происходит что то не понятное мне. Буду благодарен за объяснение корректное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тьфу. Пока печатал текст видимо мозг догнал.

php 7.1 тупит на вставке массива в строку ( т.к. $objects ) изначально является строкой.

Поэтому для корректной работы требуется массивы инициализировать так: $objects = array();

Comment: Или `$objects = []`